# WordPress custom login database error

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, authentication

I want to make custom login for my consumers in WordPress, but get this error:

```
WordPress database error: []
SELECT * FROM wp_members WHERE email='example@example.org' and password='5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99'
Wrong Username or Password


<?php
    $email1 = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $encrypted_mypassword=md5($password);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "members";
        $wpdb->show_errors();
        $sql= $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE email='$email1' and password='$encrypted_mypassword' ");
        $wpdb->print_error();

        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
        if($count==1){
            // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
            session_register("email");
            session_register("encrypted_mypassword"); 
            header("location:login_success.php");
        }
        else {
            echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        }
    }

?>
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `var_dump` $sql. It's not what you think it is - you're passing it into `mysql_query` as a new query, but it's not an SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress `$wpdb->get_results` will return the data against your query you cannot use the outcome from this function in `mysql_query()`

you can use `count()` to check the `$sql` contains data or not

```
$count=count($sql);
```

remove these

```
/*
$result=mysql_query($sql);
        // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);


*/
```

[**Class Reference wpdb**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Answer (score 0):

First up use a `salt` when you are doing this for real - http://www.md5rainbow.com/5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99

Second have you checked that the passwords you are hashing match what is in the DB (e.g. the users weren't created with a salt?)

Third, not causing your problem, but use `mysqli`.

**EDIT**

Fourth @andrewsi has the actual problem, the `$sql` var in your code does not contain your query.

Comment: yes passwords match in DB example@example.com  5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99

Comment: I am nearly certain that @andrewsi has your problem ID'd.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql= $wpdb->get_results  ->remove this line
```

This get info from table so the $sql now is **not** suited for a query.

```
  $result=mysql_query($sql)
```

the $sql in here should be

```
$sql=" SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE email='$email1' and password='$encrypted_mypassword' "
```